# How to make a 2D region on the surface of 3D volume?

Tags: regions, finite-element-method

I am trying to define an area on a volume that I can use for a boundary condition. This is a minimum working example to show the problem my real problem involves stress analysis.

I define a region using a contour plot

```
cp = ContourPlot[
  x - 1 + ((x^2 + y^2) (x - 1))/((x + 2) (x - 2)), {x, -1.5, 
   1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, Contours -> {-1.0}, ContourShading -> False]
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[cp]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If I now try and use this region in`NDSolve` this is what happens

```
sol = NDSolve[{-Laplacian[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 1, 
   DirichletCondition[f[x, y, z] == 0, 
    z == 0 && {x, y} ∈ reg]}, 
  f, {x, y, z} ∈ Cuboid[{-2, -2, 0}, {2, 2, 2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have now noticed that this also happens with

```
  sol = NDSolve[{-Laplacian[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 1, 
   DirichletCondition[f[x, y, z] == 0, 
    z == 0 && {x, y} ∈ Circle[{0, 0}, 0.1]]}, 
  f, {x, y, z} ∈ Cuboid[{-2, -2, 0}, {2, 2, 2}]]
```

So there is something wrong with defining a region in this way. What is wrong and is there a work around? Thanks

Comment: If you have an implicit description of the region as in the examples above, does this work?: `sol = NDSolve[{-Laplacian[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 1, 
   DirichletCondition[f[x, y, z] == 0, 
    z == 0 && x - 1 + ((x^2 + y^2) (x - 1))/((x + 2) (x - 2)) < -1]}, 
  f, {x, y, z} \[Element] Cuboid[{-2, -2, 0}, {2, 2, 2}]]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes that works but I don't have an implicit description. The implicit description was only for the minimum working example. I have a region, defined by a contour,  coming out of another simulation. Thanks for the try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
rmf = RegionMember[reg];
sol = NDSolve[{-Laplacian[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 1, 
   DirichletCondition[f[x, y, z] == 0, z == 0 && rmf[{x, y}]]}, 
  f, {x, y, z} \[Element] Cuboid[{-2, -2, 0}, {2, 2, 2}]]
```

Comment: Works nicely for my problem; thank you.